# Azure search max simple fields allowed in Basic subscription level

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

As we can see in the documentation,

[Azure search-limits-quotas-capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity)

The Basic level can allow 100 simple fields but we tried with 900+ fields with it, and the index is successfully created with 900+ fields in Azure. So, can someone confirm the max limit for fields in the Basic subscription level?

Also, we can see JSON request to push documents to azure have limit in terms of 32000 documents in a single request. But we can't get max size limit with it. If we go with 1000 fields in push request, then Azure has any limitation in terms of JSON request size?

[image]

Here My Azure plan

[image]

Comment: Looks like a typo to me on the documentation page. You can open up a Github issue on that page and seek clarification from the product team.

Comment: Thanks for advising me :).